# KML <SimpleData name="FID_GIS_SU">35064</SimpleData>, what does FID_GIS_SU mean?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml

I need to parse a KML file which contains the line already shown in the title. I know it's an integer value and I'm currently storing it in code as `private final int mForrestIdGisSu;` but I'd like to know what this value is if at all possible. FID I think is "Forest I.D." and GIS might be realated to the GIS software, but I'm not sure about SU. Has anyone ever seen this before?

P.S. The KML itself is used to describe the production boundaries of different parts of a forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 'SU' is specific to the data set its part of a field name so its likely a acronym or abbreviation, for example it could stand for 'Specific Use' or 'Southern Utah' or 'State University'(these are just examples). As for my guess it might be ['Standards Unit'](https://www.for.gov.bc.ca/code/training/fpc/PDFs/Primer/Glossary.pdf#page=4);

> Standards Unit: Within each silviculture prescription or site plan
>   each block may be subdivided into a series of standards units (SU).
>   Within each SU, standards such as maximum site disturbance,
>   silviculture system and stocking standards are the same.

More about the KML structure can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#simpledata):

> `<SimpleData name="string">` This element assigns a value to the custom
>   data field identified by the name attribute. The type and name of this
>   custom data field are declared in the `<Schema>` element.

Ex:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>Easy trail</name>
  <ExtendedData>
    <SchemaData schemaUrl="#TrailHeadTypeId">
      <SimpleData name="TrailHeadName">Pi in the sky</SimpleData>
      <SimpleData name="TrailLength">3.14159</SimpleData>
      <SimpleData name="ElevationGain">10</SimpleData>
```

Comment: @Adam in GIS and particularly shapefiles, FID is a *feature* id, so it could just be the unique id number of any given polygon in the dataset (in which case SU might be standards unit as this answer suggests, or sub unit or whatever). If you always see the same number, it could be something that uniquely identifies that particular forest's polygons. The source of your KML should provide explanation of what attributes/fields are (this is usually called metadata and unfortunately isn't always present). If you include the source, someone may be familiar with or able to locate the definitions.